# How to filter date and time in one dataset based on values in another dataset

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, lubridate

Assume the following dataset (called `Active`) contains date and time records of when individuals entered and left a room over several days. Individuals are denoted by a unique `ID`, `Start` is the time they entered the room, and `End` is the time they left the room.

```
ID  Date      Start       End  
1 20-5-2021   13:00:00     13:03:00
1 20-5-2021   13:05:00     13:09:45
1 21-5-2021   12:01:00     13:00:00
2 20-5-2021   13:01:00     13:09:50
2 21-5-2021   13:15:05     14:00:00
2 21-5-2021   15:01:00     15:10:00
```

Now we have another dataset (called `Detections`) that contains when each individual (`ID`) was seen in the room:

```
ID   Date       Time 
1  20-5-2021    9:02:32
1  20-5-2021   11:02:32
1  20-5-2021   13:02:31
1  20-5-2021   13:08:00
1  20-5-2021   13:08:30
2  20-5-2021   12:07:09
2  20-5-2021   12:30:10
2  20-5-2021   13:07:09
2  21-5-2021   13:50:07
2  21-5-2021   13:51:56
```

Notice that there are instances where the `ID`s were seen outside of the `Start` and `End` times in `Active`. We want to filter the rows in `Detections` where each `ID` was seen within any of the `Start` and `End` boundaries specified in `Active`. What is the best way to format the `Date` and `Time` data, and how can we apply this kind of filter with it in R?

The end result would return the rows from `Detections` where an `ID` was seen within the `Start` and `End` boundaries specified in `Active`, like this:

```
1  20-5-2021   13:02:31
1  20-5-2021   13:08:00
1  20-5-2021   13:08:30
2  20-5-2021   13:07:09
2  21-5-2021   13:50:07
2  21-5-2021   13:51:56
```

Comment: [join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) by id and date, then filter on time so it is within start and end time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine date and time column to create date-time and use `fuzzyjoin` package to join in range

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

Active %>%
  mutate(Start = dmy_hms(paste(Date, Start)), 
         End = dmy_hms(paste(Date, End))) %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(Detections %>%
  unite(Datetime, Date, Time, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(Datetime = dmy_hms(Datetime)), 
  by = c('ID', 'Start' = 'Datetime', 'End' = 'Datetime'), 
  match_fun = c(`==`, `<=`, `>=`))

#  ID.x               Start                 End ID.y            Datetime
#1    1 2021-05-20 13:00:00 2021-05-20 13:03:00    1 2021-05-20 13:02:31
#2    1 2021-05-20 13:05:00 2021-05-20 13:09:45    1 2021-05-20 13:08:00
#3    1 2021-05-20 13:05:00 2021-05-20 13:09:45    1 2021-05-20 13:08:30
#4    2 2021-05-20 13:01:00 2021-05-20 13:09:50    2 2021-05-20 13:07:09
#5    2 2021-05-21 13:15:05 2021-05-21 14:00:00    2 2021-05-21 13:50:07
#6    2 2021-05-21 13:15:05 2021-05-21 14:00:00    2 2021-05-21 13:51:56
```